# Protect routes with oauth2

Tags: php, rest, oauth-2.0, zend-framework3

I want to protect my REST API by using an oauth2 authentication. I'm using bshaffer/oauth2-server-php in combination with zend 3.
I've the following config:

```
// autoload/oauth2.global.php
return [
  'zf-oauth2' => [
    'db' => [
      'dsn' => sprintf(
        'mysql:dbname=%s;host=%s',
        false !== getenv('DB_NAME') ? getenv('DB_NAME') : '',
        false !== getenv('DB_HOST') ? getenv('DB_HOST') : ''
      ),
      'username' => false !== getenv('DB_USER') ? getenv('DB_USER') : '',
      'password' => false !== getenv('DB_PASS') ? getenv('DB_PASS') : '',
    ],
    'storage' => MyApp\OAuth2Module\Adapter\PdoAdapter::class,
    'enforce_state' => true,
    'allow_implicit' => true,
    'access_lifetime' => 3600,
    'api_problem_error_response' => false,
    'options' => [
      'use_jwt_access_tokens' => false,
      'store_encrypted_token_string' => true,
      'use_openid_connect' => false,
      'id_lifetime' => 3600,
      'www_realm' => 'Service',
      'token_param_name' => 'access_token',
      'token_bearer_header_name' => 'Bearer',
      'require_exact_redirect_uri' => true,
      'allow_public_clients' => true,
      'allow_credentials_in_request_body' => true,
      'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => false,
      'refresh_token_lifetime' => 1209600,
    ],
  ],
];
```

And my auth route looks like this:

```
// autoload/router.global.php
return [
  'router' => [
    'routes' => [
      'api' => [
        'type' => Literal::class,
        'options' => [
          'route' => '/api',
        ],
        'may_terminate' => false,
        'child_routes' => [
          'rest' => [
            'type' => Literal::class,
            'options' => [
              'route' => '/rest',
            ],
            'may_terminate' => false,
            'child_routes' => [
              'oauth' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                  'route' => '/oauth',
                  'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'ZF\OAuth2\Controller\Auth',
                    'action' => 'token',
                  ],
                ],
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Everything works fine so far. I can post my client credentials to the oauth endpoint and get an access token.
But how can I protect the other endpoints? F.e. I make a GET request to /api/rest/myapp/GetList. The list of my entities should only be retrieved if the user also sends the authorization bearer with the request but I can't find a solution for this. Is it possible to set a parameter (something like "require_token") in the route config to "activate" this behavior? Or what is the correct way to protect my REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no build-in system to make this. You will create a listener which's listens MvcEvent::Event_ROUTE and place it after router then check if there's a routematch. If there's one, check if it's protected route. If it's apply authentication logic.